# What personal story missions in Heart of Thorns require a specific mastery?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Every review I've read about Guild Wars 2: Heart of Thorns mentions a certain amount of frustration from the author in that certain personal story missions require the player to have a certain mastery unlocked, a mastery that the author doesn't yet have unlocked, meaning they're gated behind their normal progression.

Because I'm basically interested in just the personal story and any jumping puzzles that might be in the Maguuma Jungle, I want to avoid getting myself gated as much as possible. Which masteries should I have at what level for what missions?

Comment: In the first week after HoT released, there was a mission about 2/3 of the way through that required a high level Nuhoch mastery, and a lot of people were unhappy about that. Arenanet quickly responded to the negative comments about "mastery gating" the story, and removed that requirement. That's why reviews of the story often complain about mastery requirements. There are still some mastery requirements in the story, but they're all low level ones now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of story missions that require various masteries, but none of them are high-level masteries. The biggest issue was a requirement for Itzel Poison Lore (Itzel IV), but this was removed soon after launch.

The story instances that require certain masteries are:

Act I:

- [Establish a foothold](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Establishing_a_Foothold): [Glider Basics](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glider_Basics) (Gliding I)
- [In their Footsteps](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/In_Their_Footsteps): [Bouncing Mushrooms](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bouncing_Mushrooms) (Itzel I)

Act II:

- [City of Hope](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/City_of_Hope): [Exalted Markings](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Exalted_Markings) (Exalted I)
- [The Predator's Path](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Predator's_Path): [Updraft Use](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Updraft_Use) (Gliding II)

Act III:

- [The Way In](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Way_In): [Nuhoch Hunting](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Nuhoch_Hunting) (Nuhoch I)

Obtaining all these Masteries will require a total of 6 Maguuma Mastery Points and 3048000 Maguuma Mastery experience (XP gained in the Heart of Thorns zones). Note that all Heart of Thorns story instances award a [Writ of Maguuma Mastery](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Writ_of_Maguuma_Mastery) the first time it is completed on an account, and the first story mission always awards a [Tome of Maguuma Mastery](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tome_of_Maguuma_Mastery).

Comment: Be sure to keep a utility buff, exp booster and exp+ food handy to speed things up.